# Kernel parameter intel_iommu=on causes boot to fail

Tags: grub2, 16.04, kernel, virtualization

Using the stock kernel (4.4.0-34-generic and 4.4.0-31-generic) and a fresh install of 16.04.  VT-d is supported by my hardware (Xeon E3-1245 v5 and the ASrock Rack C236M WS motherboard), and is enabled in the BIOS.  I called ASrock tech support and the guy there ensured me that VT-d is supported.

During a failing boot, I see the kernel messages scroll past too fast to read (I removed `quiet` and `splash`) for about a second or three (booting from an SSD) before the screen shows a bunch of lines and the system becomes completely unresponsive.  It looks to me like the failure happens right after the GUI is started - first the console is a crappy resolution, then it has a higher resolution for a second before failing.

[After it failed I pulled the drive and copied out the syslog, here's the whole thing.](http://pastebin.com/7JuuXJhV)

It looks to me like everything starts to shut down after all the gnome-session assertion failures.  But why would enabling PCI passthrough in the kernel kill gnome-session?

I'm leaning toward this being an obscure hardware bug of some kind, because when I set `intel_iommu=soft`, Ubuntu boots ok, and dmesg reports IOMMU enabled, but it doesn't actually work (nothing appears in `/sys/kernel/iommu_groups`).  No other kernel parameters that I've tried have done anything different, except that a successful boot gives me `x2apic is disabled because BIOS sets x2apic opt out bit` in syslog, and setting `intremap=no_x2apic_optout` makes the message go away.

**EDIT**

(Added exact kernel versions at the top.)

I had a Crunchbang++ (basically just reskinned Debian Jessie) install disc laying around so I installed that on a spare drive and it booted FINE with IOMMU functioning!  The default, functioning kernel was 3.16.0-4-amd64.

Part of the reason I wanted to go Ubuntu with this project was for the recent kernels, so I tried installing the jessie-backports kernel (4.6.0-0.bpo.1-amd64) and got the exact same failure as with Ubuntu ([see what it looks like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYCJt.jpg)).

Now my guess is there was some IOMMU-related change or feature addition after 3.16 which doesn't play nice with this hardware.  Anyone have any ideas, other than try another board or be happy with 3.16 kernel?

Comment: Instead of saying "most recent kernel" can you say "kernel version 4.7.2" or "version 4.8-rc3" or "4.4.0-31.50" to remove ambiguity? It might change the answers you will get.

Comment: To change your screen "crappy"  resolution check out [HOWTO: Change bootup resolution] (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=258484).

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've done some kernel digging and added the exact versions.